# Vue displaying array elements via search on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm learning Vue Js and I found myself a little bit lost here. I want to display array elements from Rest API depending on what id do you search for. For instance: my Json File includes different people with different Ids and if I search for one particular id i want to display that exact person's information with the id that he is assigned with.

So i tried using array.filter function, however I'm assigning creditId value from search to an url query. ("http://localhost:8080/#/search?creditid=123") And i want the query to call the display info function.

So these are my fetching data from my REST API and pushing the creditid query of the value in the search bar.

```
export default {

     name: 'app',
     data(){
         return{
             creditid: '',
             credits: [],
             userFilterKey: ''
         }
     },
     mounted() {
         this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/credits')
         .then(function (res) {
             this.credits = res.body;
         })
         .catch(function (error) {
             console.log('Error: ', error);
         })
     },
     methods: {
         pushing(creditid) {
             this.$router.push({name: 'search', query: {creditid}});
         }
     }

}
```

This is my search input and a search button:

```
 <div class="container">
     <input for="search-credit" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Credit ID" aria-label="Search" v-model.trim="creditid">
     <router-view/>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="search-credit" @click="pushing(creditid)">Search</button>
 </div>
```

And my JSON file looks like this:

```
 [
     {
         "creditId": 123,
         "id": 1,
         "client": "Tom",
         "sport": "basketball"
     },
     {
         "creditId": 789,
         "id": 2,
         "client": "Peter",
         "sport": "soccer",
     }
 ]
```

To conclude: I want to display person's data depending on what creditid you type to the search input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `computed property` to filter out results you fetched in mounted hook. You can check out vue.js documentation example with similar functionality here - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component.

If you want to make separate API call for every search request, then just implement search method and use your `this.creditid` as parameter and replace `credits` array with API response data - example https://jsfiddle.net/qrwn568g/1/ (added axios for http request handling and tailwind for a little styling)

Comment: Please explain how to implement search method and replace an array with API response data